# Shopware 6 - shopping experiences layout for search results

Tags: shopware, storefront, shopware6

i'm using Shopware 6.3.0.1.
is there currently a possibility to assign a standard layout from the shopping experiences to the search results?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible by now. Everytime you create a new category in the administration it is created with no cmsPage selected at all.

Depending on the way you create the category there are ways to hook into the code and set one on creation as well. I assume an event subscriber listening for the creation of a category entry is a way to do it.

Comment: Is the search result page a regular categoy listing?

Comment: No. The search result page is in the route `frontend.search.page` which calls `SearchController::search` which renders `Storefront/storefront/page/search/index.html.twig` which is just the cms components for filtering and listing. No cmsPage used there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently shopware doesn't support cmsPages for the search result.
You can vote for this Feature Request:
https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-10403